# The coefficient of $x^k$in the expansion of $\dfrac{1-2x-x^2}{e^x}$ is

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The coefficient of $x^k$in the expansion of $\dfrac{1-2x-x^2}{e^x}$ is

This a question of university entrance examination, which my teachers didn't taught me and not in my syllabus.

I referred got this equation from Hall and Knight Algebra :

> Coefficient of $x^r$ in the expansion of $\dfrac{1-ax-x^2}{e^x}$  is
>   given by $$\dfrac{-1^r}{r!}\{1+ar-r(r-1)\}$$

However applying this answer gives me :

$$\dfrac{-1^k}{k!}(1+3k-k^2)$$

This doesn't match any of the choice given :

(A)$\:\dfrac{1-k-k^2}{k!}\qquad$
(B)$\:\dfrac{1-k}{k!}\qquad$
(C)$\:\dfrac{k^2+1}{k!}\qquad$
(D)$\:\dfrac{1}{k!}\qquad$
(E)$\:\dfrac{1+k}{k!}$

Comment: For one thing, you are missing some "$(-1)^r$"-s now and then.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, edited now.

Answer (score 5):

$$(1-2x-x^2)e^{-x}=
(1-2x-x^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$
I reckon the $x^k$ coefficent is
$$(-1)^k\frac1{k!}-(-1)^{k-1}2\frac1{(k-1)!}
-(-1)^{k-2}\frac{1}{(k-2)!}
=(-1)^k\frac{1+2k-k(k-1)}{k!}.$$
What does this simplify to?